# Stop scrolling to the bottom automatically in PuTTY

Tags: linux, terminal, putty, tail

I am using `tail -f` to monitor a file via PuTTY. But each time new content arrives then it automatically scrolls to the bottom and so I can't read the text.

Is there a way to make it stop that behaviour?

Comment: A workaround not specific to PuTTY: [probably with Ctrl+s you can tell the remote pseudoterminal to stop giving you data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137842/108618); new content will not arrive until you send Ctrl+q.

Comment: Also not specific to PuTTY, if you use GNU screen or tmux, copy mode will let you scroll arbitrarily without resetting to the bottom automatically, though it will usually not show updates until you leave copy mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On *PuTTY Configuration* window, go to *Window* page.

And uncheck *"Reset scrollback on display activity"*.

[image]

[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `tail -f` you can also use `less +F filename` to follow the file. Then to stop following use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> / <kbd>Shift+F</kbd> to toggle between follow mode and manual scrolling.

Use <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit `less`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also freeze and resume the terminal using Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q

```
$ stty -a
...; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; ...
```

Comment: I like to think of it as S=suspend, Q=qontinue (C was already taken).

Comment: @Andrew Morton Suspend is something else (^Z)

Comment: That'll be zuspend then :)